# Using hex numbers in MSP430 assembler

Tags: assembly, hex, msp430

I'm new to assembly (we are using it at school with an MSP430 controller) and I'm trying to do two things.

1. moving an hex number to a certain location: `mov #FFFh, R5` (moving it into the fifth register)
2. comparing an hex number with another: `cmp #FFFh, #45`

```
            mov.b #0, R4 ; indice
            mov.b #0, R5 ; contatore

            bis.b #00000001b, P1DIR ; led rosso
            bis.b #10000000b, P4DIR    ; led verde

main_loop:  cmp #19, R5
            jz end
            cmp #FFFFh, 2C00h(R4)
            jnz nope
            jmp yep

nope:       inc.b R4
            jmp main_loop

yep:        inc.b R4
            inc.b R5
            jmp main_loop

end:        cmp #5, R5
            jge red_led
            jmp green_led

red_led:    bis.b #00000001b, P1OUT
green_led:  bis.b #10000000b, P4OUT
```

The compiler log (we are using CCS, CodeComposer) says:

> "../main.asm", ERROR!   at EOF: [E0300] The following symbols are undefined:
>     FFFFh

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show us both your actual source code and the error messages you got. Without both of these, it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @fuz edited with the source

Comment: What happens after the last instruction? Is this your entire program?

Comment: Don't know about the msp assembly, but generally you start a number with a digit, like `0FFFFh`, to separate it from a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word starting with a digit (`0` … `9`) is interpreted as a number.
A word starting with a letter (`A` … `Z`) is interpreted as a name (of a register or a variable or a label).

So when a hexadecimal number starts with a letter, you must add a zero:

```
        cmp #0FFFFh, 2C00h(R4)
```